# Autocorrect to italics: font remains italicized

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

I am able to set Word 2010 to Autocorrect certain words to italics (for example, correct i.e. to *i.e.*). However, when I try this, after the auto-replacement the cursor remains italicized, so then I'd have to manually turn italics off each time. I've tried a million combinations of the way I select *i.e.* before entering it into the autocorrect list. I wish I could try to add "*i.e.* " instead of "*i.e.*" and make sure the space isn't italicized, but Word won't accept an autocorrect entry ending with a space. Anyone manage to do this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

If you use *i.e*. rather than *i.e.* (that is, leaving the last period un-italicized), then the cursor won't be italicized after the auto-correct. (Depending on the font and size, that last plain text period might not be noticeable.)